# What is this assembly doing?

Tags: disassembly, assembly

I wrote a very basic crackme to learn how assembly works.

Even though I wrote it myself, I am having some trouble understanding a few pieces of the assembly:

[image]

What I know up to now is: `[rbp+rax+input_buffer]` is basically `input_buffer[rax]`, xor'ing two of the same registers resets them and that's about it (apart from the very basic stuff like add, mov, inc).

I specifically don't understand what `movsx ..` and `add ecx, 0FFF..` is doing.

<s>The input_buffer is filled with `_fgets`. I'm intentionally not saying a working input to see if you can figure it out (it shouldn't be hard anyways).</s>

A proper input would be `0123456789\n`, note that I discard the newline via `strcspn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the original code is something like:

```
char input_buffer[...];
// ...
int c = input_buffer[i];
```

Since the variable `c` is a `int` and `input_buffer` is a `char[]`, your compiler has to promote the read `char` as a `int`. That's why you have the `movsx` instruction. It will read the current character and sign extend it, so it'll fit to a `int`.

About the `add`, it's common for a compiler to encode a `sub dst, imm` as `add dst, -imm`, if you negate `0xffffffd0` (SHIFT - in IDA), you'll obtain `-0x30`. This is how you convert the ASCII digit into a integer.